# how to take the feedback for vision based lane keeping control system

Tags: matlab

I am working on vision based lane detection. My problem is that if we consider this block diagram:

[image: Block Diagram]

I have done with each block individually but I am confused while connecting them.

Consider for an image, image is taken values are measured by the sensor, error is calculated between reference value and value from sensor then given to `pid` and then to space state, but according to second block diagram:

[image: Second Block Diagram]

The value from space state is taken as feed back and error is calculated. Now I am confused where to take feed back to.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Judging  from your image, the feedback should be input for the PID controller during the next cycle. Either directly or through some function that merges the feedback with the reference.

Comment: The block diagram is for 'Vision based vehicle lane keeping control system'. According to my understanding; my system has two parts; image processing and control systems. Image processing part has to detect the road lane markings and then to calculate the lateral distance between the vehicle C.G. and the center line of road. Control system part has PID controller; Whose job is to keep the vehicle in the center of the lane. Reference is input to the pid; which represents where we want our vehicle to be. Next to it space state block is attached in which mathematical modeling of the car is done.

Comment: The output of pid is steering angle. I am confused with the interconnection of the blocks. I have no idea where to connect the image processing part and where to take feedback according to second block diagram.

Comment: I still don't see the picture clearly, but from a functional point of view I would say: As soon as you detect the line you will want to adjust your steering angle.

Comment: Yes as soon as my system detect the lane I will have to adjust my steering angle if the vehicle is not in the centre of the lane.